# Update array item value from function results - javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects, where I need one value from each object to be updated with the results of a function.

```
function deg2rad(deg) {
    return deg * (Math.PI / 180)
}
function getDistanceFromStore(userLat, userLon, storeLat, storeLon) {
    var R = 3958.8; // Radius of the earth in miles
    var dLat = deg2rad(storeLat - userLat);  // deg2rad below
    var dLon = deg2rad(storeLon - userLon);
    var a =
        Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
        Math.cos(deg2rad(userLat)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(storeLat)) *
        Math.sin(dLon / 2) * Math.sin(dLon / 2)
        ;
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    var d = R * c; // Distance in miles
    return d;
}
```

Array:

```
const locations = [
    {
        location: "One",
        lat: 19.7517133,
        lng: -95.3241383,
        distance: '',
    },
    {
        location: "Two",
        lat: 19.7883441,
        lng: -95.8037025,
        distance: '',
    },
    {
        location: "Three",
        lat: 20.1523784,
        lng: -95.4474075,
        distance: '',
    },
    {
        location: "Four",
        lat: 19.53731909999999,
        lng: -95.1523701,
        distance: '',
    },
];
```

I need the function to execute for each array object and update the distance value with the resulting of the function. I haven't been able to find an answer anywhere so far.

I also have the component this is going into, where I am fetching user location data:

```
const Menu = () => {
    const [hasError, setErrors] = useState(false);
    const [userLocation, setUserLocation] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const res = await fetch('http://api.ipapi.com/api/check?access_key=' + access_key);
            res
                .json()
                .then(res => setUserLocation(res))
                .catch(err => setErrors(err));
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    var userLat = userLocation.latitude;
    var userLon = userLocation.longitude;
}
```

I'm guessing I should be getting the use data outside of the component, but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use map function on locations to get new updated version of locations. Here is some basic idea.

I think you have to use some ReactContext to store userLat and userLon in global state, so you can use it in your react app.

```
const locationsUpdated = locations.map(item => {
  const newDistance = getDistanceFromStore(userLat, userLon, item.lat, item.lng);
  return {
    ...item
    distance: newDistance
  }
});

console.log(locationsUpdated);
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my post to try to give more context

Comment: the userLat/userLon data is inside of the component, but it needs to be used in the getDistanceFromStore function, which is outside of the component. The userLat/userLon comes from data retrieved from an api. Is it possible to do the api fetch outside of the component?

Comment: It depends on how you design your app. One option could be to use browser localStorage to store userLat and userLon and then use the values outside of the component in getDistanceFromStore function.